# Create django query satisfying two conditions involving related models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have two models, let's say:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
  # ... fields

class Product(models.Model):
  quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=1)
  order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
  b_product = models.ForeignKey(BaseProduct, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class BaseProduct(models.Model):
  type = #.... choices = [rtProduct, rtPack]
```

I want to make a query that includes all the `Orders` which have more than one `Product` related to it, or if at least one `Product` has a `quantity` greater than `1`, or if the `BaseProduct` type is `rtProduct`

For the first part I have this:

```py
queryset = Order.objects.annotate(products_count=Count('products')).filter(products_count__gt=1)
```

I am stuck on adding the `OR` condition to also include the other condition.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum up the quantity and determine if the `Order` has two items or more with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Order.objects.alias(
    num_items=Sum('product__quantity')
).filter(num_items__gt=1)
```

or prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Order.objects.annotate(
    num_items=Sum('product__quantity')
).filter(num_items__gt=1)
```

If it is possible to have an `Order` object with quantity less than or equal to one, we should do this differently, and work with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Exists, OuterRef, Q

Order.objects.alias(
    n_items=Count('product')
).filter(
    Q(n_item__gt=1) | Exists(
        Product.objects.filter(order_id=OuterRef('pk'), quantity__gt=1)
    )
)
```

or prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Exists, OuterRef, Q

Order.objects.annotate(
    n_items=Count('product')
).filter(
    Q(n_item__gt=1) | Exists(
        Product.objects.filter(order_id=OuterRef('pk'), quantity__gt=1)
    )
)
```

Comment: Great answer. I forgot to mention that `Product` has types and are involved in the query. I will add it to the question. But I definitely used your solution. `p_bulk_qs = Product.objects.only('order', 'quantity', 'b_product').filter(Q(quantity__gt=1) | Q(b_product__record_type=constants.rtProduct), order_id=OuterRef('pk'))` and then `qs = Order.objects.annotate(n_items=Count('products')).filter(Q(n_items__gt=1) | Exists(p_bulk_qs ))`